# Schengen Deduction during Fiktionbescheinigung Section 81 (3)

Tags: schengen, germany, us-citizens

I am a US citizen and student doing a guest study semester in Germany in a program taught in English. I entered Germany as a tourist with Schengen visa-free entry.

I applied for a student residence permit so that I could stay until the end of the semester (a total of 6 months). They told me that they would issue me a "temporary residence permit" (in English, as I don't speak much German). I received a Fiktionbescheinigung 81 abs 3 satz 1 AufenthG until the end of the semester. However, I need to go back to the US and then go to Switzerland for a few weeks. Will my time in Germany under the Fiktionbescheinigung count toward my 90/180 Schengen time as a US citizen? Will I have issues entering and exiting Switzerland?

Comment: Even if the authorities called it a 'temporary residence permit', a fictional certificate (Fiktionsbescheinigung) is *not* a residence permit in the sense of the Schengen regulations. Be also aware that a fictional certificate (§ 81 Abs. 3 Satz 1 AufenthG) expires and loses its validity if you leave Germany.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo nonsence, [§ 81 Abs. 3 Satz 1 AufenthG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1732): *(3) If a foreigner who is legally resident in the federal territory and does not possess a residence title applies for a residence title, his or her residence ,**is deemed to be permitted up to the time of the decision by the foreigners authority**.* It is a residence permit and nowhere it is stated that they cannot leave.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Any permission, issued by a national goverment for residence, overides the Schengen rules. A permit can become invalid after an absence of 6 months. Since a Fiktionsbescheinigung is generaly issued for 3 months, this cannot happen. So where do you get these wierd notions?

Comment: @MarkJohnson A fictional certificate 81(3) is issued when applying for a residence permit to allow the foreigner to stay in Germany as long as the application is being processed and he is waiting for the decision upon his application. It is stated in the administrative regulations to the residence act that it expires when the holder leaves Germany: "Bei Ausreise aus dem Bundesgebiet erlischt die Duldungsfiktion und lebt auch bei einer erneuten Einreise nicht wieder auf." - "When leaving the federal territory, the certificate expires and does not come back into effect after a new reentry."

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo A **Duldungfiktion** is something compleaty different. That only applies to peaple who are being deported and still make an application to remain. They will not be deported until a desion is made, but if they leave they cannot return. Has absolutely **nothing** do do with this case of **Erlaubnisfiktion**, which is the case here.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo A **Duldungfiktion** is is issued based on [Section 60a - Temporary suspension of deportation (Duldung)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1278), which the administrative regulations you are quoating clearly states.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I definitely understand that my Fiktionbescheinigung will no longer be valid when I leave the country as it is issued under Abs. 3 not Abs. 4. Regardless of the definition of a residence permit, I'm curious to know how another country would view this. I am interested to know if there is a spot in the Schengen Border Code that clearly does not permit this, or that addresses it, so I can point to that part if its at all vague.

Comment: @zaumnik As a US citizen you may enter the Schengen Area without a visa. The days spent in Germany will not count fir the 90/180 rule while the Fiktionsbescheinigung is valid. It does not become invalid by leaving.

Answer (score 0):

No, while within the country that issued a residence permit (or D-Visa), the 90/180 clock does **not** count

- you are not a (short term) visitor during periods in that country, but a resident (long term)

Citizens of Australia, Israel, Japan, Canada, Neu Zealand, South Korea and the United States (who may apply for residence inside Germany), will be issued a [Fiktionsbescheinigung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiktionsbescheinigung) after such an application.

Allthough this cannot be used as a **visa replacement** to cross the **external** Schengen border (citizens of these countries don't require a visa), it is still a residence permit and the days inside Germany don't count for the 90/180 days rule.

Comment: OP has a fictional certificate and neither a residence permit nor a type D visa.

Comment: While I agree it *should* be considered a residence permit for the purpose of 90/180 and German authorities would very likely consider it to be one at the border, the Schengen Borders Code explicitly excludes temporary permits pending first application of a residence permit from its definition of a residence permit; and I am not sure if other Schengen authorities, e.g. Swiss, will take this into account, since Fiktionsbescheinigung (except under 81 abs 4) is not in the notified list of residence permits.

Comment: On that matter I don't think long-stay visa is explicitly defined in the Code so the FB might be considered to be a long-stay visa?

Comment: @xngtng [Prado Fiktionsbescheinigung,Residence-related document](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/DEU-HO-12001/index.html): certificate for foreigners in Germany as proof of a temporary right to remain when applying for a residence permit or an extension thereof.

Comment: @xngtng thank you for this information regarding the Schengen Borders Code. Do you have a link to where I could get more info on where they list which documents are considered to be a residence permit. Since I'm only going to be in potential violation when leaving Switzerland, I want to see if there is a way to argue you my point. Probably not the best move but since I will only be over by a couple days, I thought I would risk it.

Comment: @zaumnik See https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32016R0399 (article 2, point 16) and https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/default/files/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/docs/handbook-annex_22.pdf. That said, you probably have a better chance if you are going through a Germanophone country like Switzerland; but preferrably you should go through Germany who knows about its own laws.

Comment: @xngtng 2 under Germany: *All other documents issued to third-country nationals having equivalent value to a residence: **Fiktionsbescheinigung*** is listed. When point 1 is crossed, it cannot be used as a **visa replacment** to cross the external Schengen border. But citizens of Australia, Israel, Japan, Canada, Neu Zealand, South Korea and the United States (who may apply for residence inside Germany) don't need a visa to enter the Schengen Area.

Comment: @phoog I guess the dash was confusing to me, if it's only equivalent to residence permit when the first box is checked, or if it is only clarifying the role in entry. I think the latter is more reasonable.